# How can I enable legacy policy api in google login

Tags: angular

Legacy People API has not been used in project 145315848075 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=145315848075 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Before the Google+ API Shutdown on March 7, 2019, the people.get and people.getOpenIdConnect methods were available for requesting a person’s profile.
--this is from google developer

The google+ API is deprecated,so we can't get user info from google+ API that why the issue occurs.

We need to change code for getting user info, basically the google login works
like

Authenticate -> return to our site with code -> use this code to get users info

*****use this one to get user info instead what you used old one

'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile' for user profile,
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email' for email.
Go to https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#oauth2 for more info.

Comment: Can you update your answer? The link is invalid. I am facing this error and cant find the solution.

Comment: Hi Čamo, Which programming language are you using?
Because still its working for me, i am using laravel PHP with Socialite

Comment: PHP but I fix it. Its ok.